# How to perform end-to-end testing in Kubernetes using sonobuoy

Tags: kubernetes

OS: Ubuntu 18.04
These are the set of commands we executed to obtain the result of sonobuoy.
This is to perform Kubernetes end to end(or conformance) testing.

```
ubuntu@masternode:~$sonobuoy run
ubuntu@masternode:~$ results=$(sonobuoy retrieve)
ubuntu@masternode:~$ sonobuoy results $results
Plugin: e2e
Status: unknown
Total: 0
Passed: 0
Failed: 0
Skipped: 0
```

Issue: we are getting the status as unknown and total count as 0 and so on. But when we try the dryrun, we get the details as shown in the below.

```
ubuntu@masternode:~$sonobuoy run --plugin-env e2e.E2E_FOCUS=pods --plugin-env e2e.E2E_DRYRUN=true
ubuntu@masternode:~$ results=$(sonobuoy retrieve)
ubuntu@masternode:~/bin$ sonobuoy results $results
Plugin: e2e
Status: passed
Total: 4413
Passed: 354
Failed: 0
Skipped: 4059
```

Can anyone help us to fix this issue? or Share other ways to do end-to-end test in Kubernetes.

please find below the details for the logs

```
ubuntu@masternode:~$ sonobuoy status
PLUGINSTATUSRESULTCOUNT
e2ecompleteunknown1
systemd-logscompletepassed1
systemd-logscomplete9

Sonobuoy has completed. Use `sonobuoy retrieve` to get results.

ubuntu@masternode:~$ results=$(sonobuoy retrieve)
ubuntu@masternode:~$ sonobuoy results $results
Plugin: e2e
Status: unknown
Total: 0
Passed: 0
Failed: 0
Skipped: 0

Plugin: systemd-logs
Status: passed
Total: 10
Passed: 10
Failed: 0
Skipped: 0
ubuntu@masternode:~$
```

Please find below the complete log information.

```
I0122 14:06:44.242882      19 test_context.go:406] Using a temporary kubeconfig file from in-cluster config : /tmp/kubeconfig-629324578
I0122 14:06:44.242936      19 test_context.go:419] Tolerating taints "node-role.kubernetes.io/master" when considering if nodes are ready
I0122 14:06:44.245332      19 e2e.go:109] Starting e2e run "eee1f5b8-9b6f-46f7-a8c1-61f771ceee41" on Ginkgo node 1
{"msg":"Test Suite starting","total":278,"completed":0,"skipped":0,"failed":0}
Running Suite: Kubernetes e2e suite
===================================
Random Seed: 1579702001 - Will randomize all specs
Will run 278 of 4814 specs

Jan 22 14:06:44.324: INFO: >>> kubeConfig: /tmp/kubeconfig-629324578
Jan 22 14:06:44.360: INFO: Waiting up to 30m0s for all (but 0) nodes to be schedulable
Jan 22 14:06:44.428: INFO: Waiting up to 10m0s for all pods (need at least 0) in namespace 'kube-system' to be running and ready
Jan 22 14:06:44.485: INFO: 10 / 10 pods in namespace 'kube-system' are running and ready (0 seconds elapsed)
Jan 22 14:06:44.485: INFO: expected 3 pod replicas in namespace 'kube-system', 3 are Running and Ready.
Jan 22 14:06:44.485: INFO: Waiting up to 5m0s for all daemonsets in namespace 'kube-system' to start
Jan 22 14:06:44.494: INFO: 1 / 1 pods ready in namespace 'kube-system' in daemonset 'kube-proxy' (0 seconds elapsed)
Jan 22 14:06:44.494: INFO: e2e test version: v1.17.0
Jan 22 14:06:44.497: INFO: kube-apiserver version: v1.17.0
Jan 22 14:06:44.499: INFO: >>> kubeConfig: /tmp/kubeconfig-629324578
Jan 22 14:06:44.536: INFO: Cluster IP family: ipv4
SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
------------------------------
[sig-api-machinery] ResourceQuota 
  should create a ResourceQuota and ensure its status is promptly calculated. [Conformance]
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:721
[BeforeEach] [sig-api-machinery] ResourceQuota
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:151
STEP: Creating a kubernetes client
Jan 22 14:06:44.538: INFO: >>> kubeConfig: /tmp/kubeconfig-629324578
STEP: Building a namespace api object, basename resourcequota
Jan 22 14:06:44.867: INFO: No PodSecurityPolicies found; assuming PodSecurityPolicy is disabled.
STEP: Waiting for a default service account to be provisioned in namespace
[It] should create a ResourceQuota and ensure its status is promptly calculated. [Conformance]
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:721
STEP: Counting existing ResourceQuota
STEP: Creating a ResourceQuota
STEP: Ensuring resource quota status is calculated
[AfterEach] [sig-api-machinery] ResourceQuota
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:152
Jan 22 14:06:52.167: INFO: Waiting up to 3m0s for all (but 0) nodes to be ready
STEP: Destroying namespace "resourcequota-6723" for this suite.

• [SLOW TEST:7.655 seconds]
[sig-api-machinery] ResourceQuota
/workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/apimachinery/framework.go:23
  should create a ResourceQuota and ensure its status is promptly calculated. [Conformance]
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:721
------------------------------
{"msg":"PASSED [sig-api-machinery] ResourceQuota should create a ResourceQuota and ensure its status is promptly calculated. [Conformance]","total":278,"completed":1,"skipped":28,"failed":0}
SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
------------------------------
[sig-network] DNS 
  should provide DNS for ExternalName services [Conformance]
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:721
[BeforeEach] [sig-network] DNS
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:151
STEP: Creating a kubernetes client
Jan 22 14:06:52.240: INFO: >>> kubeConfig: /tmp/kubeconfig-629324578
STEP: Building a namespace api object, basename dns
STEP: Waiting for a default service account to be provisioned in namespace
[It] should provide DNS for ExternalName services [Conformance]
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:721
STEP: Creating a test externalName service
STEP: Running these commands on wheezy: for i in `seq 1 30`; do dig +short dns-test-service-3.dns-5567.svc.cluster.local CNAME > /results/wheezy_udp@dns-test-service-3.dns-5567.svc.cluster.local; sleep 1; done

STEP: Running these commands on jessie: for i in `seq 1 30`; do dig +short dns-test-service-3.dns-5567.svc.cluster.local CNAME > /results/jessie_udp@dns-test-service-3.dns-5567.svc.cluster.local; sleep 1; done

STEP: creating a pod to probe DNS
STEP: submitting the pod to kubernetes
STEP: retrieving the pod
STEP: looking for the results for each expected name from probers
Jan 22 14:07:03.221: INFO: DNS probes using dns-test-6066c047-1fcb-4fae-a7d1-dd929f2e0339 succeeded

STEP: deleting the pod
STEP: changing the externalName to bar.example.com
STEP: Running these commands on wheezy: for i in `seq 1 30`; do dig +short dns-test-service-3.dns-5567.svc.cluster.local CNAME > /results/wheezy_udp@dns-test-service-3.dns-5567.svc.cluster.local; sleep 1; done

STEP: Running these commands on jessie: for i in `seq 1 30`; do dig +short dns-test-service-3.dns-5567.svc.cluster.local CNAME > /results/jessie_udp@dns-test-service-3.dns-5567.svc.cluster.local; sleep 1; done

STEP: creating a second pod to probe DNS
STEP: submitting the pod to kubernetes
STEP: retrieving the pod
STEP: looking for the results for each expected name from probers
Jan 22 14:07:12.319: INFO: File wheezy_udp@dns-test-service-3.dns-5567.svc.cluster.local from pod  dns-5567/dns-test-30128437-ecc3-4c91-b41d-334389a55e70 contains '' instead of 'bar.example.com.'
Jan 22 14:07:12.327: INFO: File jessie_udp@dns-test-service-3.dns-5567.svc.cluster.local from pod  dns-5567/dns-test-30128437-ecc3-4c91-b41d-334389a55e70 contains 'foo.example.com.
' instead of 'bar.example.com.'
Jan 22 14:07:12.327: INFO: Lookups using dns-5567/dns-test-30128437-ecc3-4c91-b41d-334389a55e70 failed for: [wheezy_udp@dns-test-service-3.dns-5567.svc.cluster.local jessie_udp@dns-test-service-3.dns-5567.svc.cluster.local]

Jan 22 14:07:17.400: INFO: File wheezy_udp@dns-test-service-3.dns-5567.svc.cluster.local from pod  dns-5567/dns-test-30128437-ecc3-4c91-b41d-334389a55e70 contains 'foo.example.com.
' instead of 'bar.example.com.'
Jan 22 14:07:17.409: INFO: File jessie_udp@dns-test-service-3.dns-5567.svc.cluster.local from pod  dns-5567/dns-test-30128437-ecc3-4c91-b41d-334389a55e70 contains 'foo.example.com.
' instead of 'bar.example.com.'
Jan 22 14:07:17.409: INFO: Lookups using dns-5567/dns-test-30128437-ecc3-4c91-b41d-334389a55e70 failed for: [wheezy_udp@dns-test-service-3.dns-5567.svc.cluster.local jessie_udp@dns-test-service-3.dns-5567.svc.cluster.local]

Jan 22 14:07:22.447: INFO: File wheezy_udp@dns-test-service-3.dns-5567.svc.cluster.local from pod  dns-5567/dns-test-30128437-ecc3-4c91-b41d-334389a55e70 contains 'foo.example.com.
' instead of 'bar.example.com.'
Jan 22 14:07:22.469: INFO: File jessie_udp@dns-test-service-3.dns-5567.svc.cluster.local from pod  dns-5567/dns-test-30128437-ecc3-4c91-b41d-334389a55e70 contains 'foo.example.com.
' instead of 'bar.example.com.'
Jan 22 14:07:22.469: INFO: Lookups using dns-5567/dns-test-30128437-ecc3-4c91-b41d-334389a55e70 failed for: [wheezy_udp@dns-test-service-3.dns-5567.svc.cluster.local jessie_udp@dns-test-service-3.dns-5567.svc.cluster.local]

Jan 22 14:07:27.359: INFO: File wheezy_udp@dns-test-service-3.dns-5567.svc.cluster.local from pod  dns-5567/dns-test-30128437-ecc3-4c91-b41d-334389a55e70 contains 'foo.example.com.
' instead of 'bar.example.com.'
Jan 22 14:07:27.372: INFO: File jessie_udp@dns-test-service-3.dns-5567.svc.cluster.local from pod  dns-5567/dns-test-30128437-ecc3-4c91-b41d-334389a55e70 contains 'foo.example.com.
' instead of 'bar.example.com.'
Jan 22 14:07:27.372: INFO: Lookups using dns-5567/dns-test-30128437-ecc3-4c91-b41d-334389a55e70 failed for: [wheezy_udp@dns-test-service-3.dns-5567.svc.cluster.local jessie_udp@dns-test-service-3.dns-5567.svc.cluster.local]

Jan 22 14:07:32.360: INFO: DNS probes using dns-test-30128437-ecc3-4c91-b41d-334389a55e70 succeeded

STEP: deleting the pod
STEP: changing the service to type=ClusterIP
STEP: Running these commands on wheezy: for i in `seq 1 30`; do dig +short dns-test-service-3.dns-5567.svc.cluster.local A > /results/wheezy_udp@dns-test-service-3.dns-5567.svc.cluster.local; sleep 1; done

STEP: Running these commands on jessie: for i in `seq 1 30`; do dig +short dns-test-service-3.dns-5567.svc.cluster.local A > /results/jessie_udp@dns-test-service-3.dns-5567.svc.cluster.local; sleep 1; done

STEP: creating a third pod to probe DNS
STEP: submitting the pod to kubernetes
STEP: retrieving the pod
STEP: looking for the results for each expected name from probers
Jan 22 14:07:42.321: INFO: DNS probes using dns-test-90181d81-8194-4eef-9c53-7f8a5a358926 succeeded

STEP: deleting the pod
STEP: deleting the test externalName service
[AfterEach] [sig-network] DNS
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:152
Jan 22 14:07:42.744: INFO: Waiting up to 3m0s for all (but 0) nodes to be ready
STEP: Destroying namespace "dns-5567" for this suite.

• [SLOW TEST:50.771 seconds]
[sig-network] DNS
/workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/network/framework.go:23
  should provide DNS for ExternalName services [Conformance]
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:721
------------------------------
{"msg":"PASSED [sig-network] DNS should provide DNS for ExternalName services [Conformance]","total":278,"completed":2,"skipped":64,"failed":0}
SS
------------------------------
[sig-storage] Projected downwardAPI 
  should set mode on item file [LinuxOnly] [NodeConformance] [Conformance]
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:721
[BeforeEach] [sig-storage] Projected downwardAPI
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:151
STEP: Creating a kubernetes client
Jan 22 14:07:43.020: INFO: >>> kubeConfig: /tmp/kubeconfig-629324578
STEP: Building a namespace api object, basename projected
STEP: Waiting for a default service account to be provisioned in namespace
[BeforeEach] [sig-storage] Projected downwardAPI
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/common/projected_downwardapi.go:40
[It] should set mode on item file [LinuxOnly] [NodeConformance] [Conformance]
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:721
STEP: Creating a pod to test downward API volume plugin
Jan 22 14:07:44.199: INFO: Waiting up to 5m0s for pod "downwardapi-volume-14c007eb-95d5-4542-beb9-86eff0d7f3f4" in namespace "projected-8175" to be "success or failure"
Jan 22 14:07:44.267: INFO: Pod "downwardapi-volume-14c007eb-95d5-4542-beb9-86eff0d7f3f4": Phase="Pending", Reason="", readiness=false. Elapsed: 67.814089ms
Jan 22 14:07:46.403: INFO: Pod "downwardapi-volume-14c007eb-95d5-4542-beb9-86eff0d7f3f4": Phase="Pending", Reason="", readiness=false. Elapsed: 2.203995191s
Jan 22 14:07:48.566: INFO: Pod "downwardapi-volume-14c007eb-95d5-4542-beb9-86eff0d7f3f4": Phase="Pending", Reason="", readiness=false. Elapsed: 4.366650294s
Jan 22 14:07:50.636: INFO: Pod "downwardapi-volume-14c007eb-95d5-4542-beb9-86eff0d7f3f4": Phase="Succeeded", Reason="", readiness=false. Elapsed: 6.436737299s
STEP: Saw pod success
Jan 22 14:07:50.639: INFO: Pod "downwardapi-volume-14c007eb-95d5-4542-beb9-86eff0d7f3f4" satisfied condition "success or failure"
Jan 22 14:07:50.752: INFO: Trying to get logs from node minikube pod downwardapi-volume-14c007eb-95d5-4542-beb9-86eff0d7f3f4 container client-container: <nil>
STEP: delete the pod
Jan 22 14:07:51.157: INFO: Waiting for pod downwardapi-volume-14c007eb-95d5-4542-beb9-86eff0d7f3f4 to disappear
Jan 22 14:07:51.263: INFO: Pod downwardapi-volume-14c007eb-95d5-4542-beb9-86eff0d7f3f4 no longer exists
[AfterEach] [sig-storage] Projected downwardAPI
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:152
Jan 22 14:07:51.277: INFO: Waiting up to 3m0s for all (but 0) nodes to be ready
STEP: Destroying namespace "projected-8175" for this suite.

• [SLOW TEST:8.319 seconds]
[sig-storage] Projected downwardAPI
/workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/common/projected_downwardapi.go:34
  should set mode on item file [LinuxOnly] [NodeConformance] [Conformance]
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:721
------------------------------
{"msg":"PASSED [sig-storage] Projected downwardAPI should set mode on item file [LinuxOnly] [NodeConformance] [Conformance]","total":278,"completed":3,"skipped":66,"failed":0}
SSSSSSSSSS
------------------------------
[sig-api-machinery] ResourceQuota 
  should verify ResourceQuota with best effort scope. [Conformance]
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:721
[BeforeEach] [sig-api-machinery] ResourceQuota
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:151
STEP: Creating a kubernetes client
Jan 22 14:07:51.351: INFO: >>> kubeConfig: /tmp/kubeconfig-629324578
STEP: Building a namespace api object, basename resourcequota
STEP: Waiting for a default service account to be provisioned in namespace
[It] should verify ResourceQuota with best effort scope. [Conformance]
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:721
STEP: Creating a ResourceQuota with best effort scope
STEP: Ensuring ResourceQuota status is calculated
STEP: Creating a ResourceQuota with not best effort scope
STEP: Ensuring ResourceQuota status is calculated
STEP: Creating a best-effort pod
STEP: Ensuring resource quota with best effort scope captures the pod usage
STEP: Ensuring resource quota with not best effort ignored the pod usage
STEP: Deleting the pod
STEP: Ensuring resource quota status released the pod usage
STEP: Creating a not best-effort pod
STEP: Ensuring resource quota with not best effort scope captures the pod usage
STEP: Ensuring resource quota with best effort scope ignored the pod usage
STEP: Deleting the pod
STEP: Ensuring resource quota status released the pod usage
[AfterEach] [sig-api-machinery] ResourceQuota
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:152
Jan 22 14:08:09.870: INFO: Waiting up to 3m0s for all (but 0) nodes to be ready
STEP: Destroying namespace "resourcequota-4593" for this suite.

• [SLOW TEST:18.553 seconds]
[sig-api-machinery] ResourceQuota
/workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/apimachinery/framework.go:23
  should verify ResourceQuota with best effort scope. [Conformance]
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:721
------------------------------
{"msg":"PASSED [sig-api-machinery] ResourceQuota should verify ResourceQuota with best effort scope. [Conformance]","total":278,"completed":4,"skipped":76,"failed":0}
SS
------------------------------
[sig-storage] Projected configMap 
  should be consumable from pods in volume with mappings and Item mode set [LinuxOnly] [NodeConformance] [Conformance]
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:721
[BeforeEach] [sig-storage] Projected configMap
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:151
STEP: Creating a kubernetes client
Jan 22 14:08:09.911: INFO: >>> kubeConfig: /tmp/kubeconfig-629324578
STEP: Building a namespace api object, basename projected
STEP: Waiting for a default service account to be provisioned in namespace
[It] should be consumable from pods in volume with mappings and Item mode set [LinuxOnly] [NodeConformance] [Conformance]
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:721
STEP: Creating configMap with name projected-configmap-test-volume-map-f038deb5-0ddd-40d1-9407-453ccd62068f
STEP: Creating a pod to test consume configMaps
Jan 22 14:08:10.345: INFO: Waiting up to 5m0s for pod "pod-projected-configmaps-13bfc9cd-1c74-47d6-8e92-31be083da410" in namespace "projected-1124" to be "success or failure"
Jan 22 14:08:10.451: INFO: Pod "pod-projected-configmaps-13bfc9cd-1c74-47d6-8e92-31be083da410": Phase="Pending", Reason="", readiness=false. Elapsed: 106.024979ms
Jan 22 14:08:12.584: INFO: Pod "pod-projected-configmaps-13bfc9cd-1c74-47d6-8e92-31be083da410": Phase="Pending", Reason="", readiness=false. Elapsed: 2.239448334s
Jan 22 14:08:14.635: INFO: Pod "pod-projected-configmaps-13bfc9cd-1c74-47d6-8e92-31be083da410": Phase="Pending", Reason="", readiness=false. Elapsed: 4.289832483s
Jan 22 14:08:16.711: INFO: Pod "pod-projected-configmaps-13bfc9cd-1c74-47d6-8e92-31be083da410": Phase="Succeeded", Reason="", readiness=false. Elapsed: 6.36605145s
STEP: Saw pod success
Jan 22 14:08:16.712: INFO: Pod "pod-projected-configmaps-13bfc9cd-1c74-47d6-8e92-31be083da410" satisfied condition "success or failure"
Jan 22 14:08:16.807: INFO: Trying to get logs from node minikube pod pod-projected-configmaps-13bfc9cd-1c74-47d6-8e92-31be083da410 container projected-configmap-volume-test: <nil>
STEP: delete the pod
Jan 22 14:08:17.020: INFO: Waiting for pod pod-projected-configmaps-13bfc9cd-1c74-47d6-8e92-31be083da410 to disappear
Jan 22 14:08:17.030: INFO: Pod pod-projected-configmaps-13bfc9cd-1c74-47d6-8e92-31be083da410 no longer exists
[AfterEach] [sig-storage] Projected configMap
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:152
Jan 22 14:08:17.034: INFO: Waiting up to 3m0s for all (but 0) nodes to be ready
STEP: Destroying namespace "projected-1124" for this suite.

• [SLOW TEST:7.226 seconds]
[sig-storage] Projected configMap
/workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/common/projected_configmap.go:34
  should be consumable from pods in volume with mappings and Item mode set [LinuxOnly] [NodeConformance] [Conformance]
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:721
------------------------------
{"msg":"PASSED [sig-storage] Projected configMap should be consumable from pods in volume with mappings and Item mode set [LinuxOnly] [NodeConformance] [Conformance]","total":278,"completed":5,"skipped":78,"failed":0}
SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
------------------------------
[k8s.io] Pods 
  should contain environment variables for services [NodeConformance] [Conformance]
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:721
[BeforeEach] [k8s.io] Pods
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:151
STEP: Creating a kubernetes client
Jan 22 14:08:17.145: INFO: >>> kubeConfig: /tmp/kubeconfig-629324578
STEP: Building a namespace api object, basename pods
STEP: Waiting for a default service account to be provisioned in namespace
[BeforeEach] [k8s.io] Pods
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/common/pods.go:177
[It] should contain environment variables for services [NodeConformance] [Conformance]
  /workspace/anago-v1.17.0-rc.2.10+70132b0f130acc/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:721

Ginkgo ran 1 suite in 1m38.668464378s
Test Suite Failed
```

Comment: what is the output of sonobuoy logs

Comment: Please find the updated log information in the original message.

Comment: Updated e2e.log file